# growing UITextView disabling UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextview

I'm trying to implement a growing UITextView with the content size, I am using [this class](https://github.com/hsusmita/GrowingTextViewHandler-objc) and autolayout and it works great but my problem is that my **inner scroll view** is not scrolling.

**It was scrolling before adding the methods for growing text view in viewDidLoad.**

This is what is in my xib:

[image]

- View

  - outerScrollView

    - innerScrollView

      - labels
    - Growing UITextView

I do this to switch scrolling between scrollview

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if([scrollView isEqual:self.innerScrollview]){
        self.outerScrollview.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self.innerScrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    else{
        self.outerScrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
        self.innerScrollview.scrollEnabled = NO;

    }

}
```

and in **viewDidLoad** where the "msg" is the growing textview:

```
self.msgHandler = [[GrowingTextViewHandler alloc]initWithTextView:self.msg withHeightConstraint:self.msgHeight];
    [self.msgHandler updateMinimumNumberOfLines:1 andMaximumNumberOfLine:INT_MAX];
```

and in **textViewDidChange**

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.msgHandler resizeTextViewWithAnimation:YES];
}
```

so why is the growing text affecting the scrolling of the inner scrollview?

```
int outerContentHeight = self.outer_last_label.frame.size.height + self.outer_last_label.frame.origin.y; 

int innerContentHeight = self.inner_last_label.frame.size.height + self.inner_last_label.frame.origin.y; 

[self.outerSrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,outerContentHeight)]; 

[self.innerScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollview2.frame.size.width, innerContentHeight)];
```

**I have managed to fix it but I removed the use of the class"GrowingTextViewHandler" and I did this instead**

I changed "scrollViewDidScroll" to this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if([scrollView isEqual:self.innerScrollview]){
        [self.view insertSubview:self.innerScrollview atIndex:0];
    }
    else{
        [self.view insertSubview:self.outerScrollview atIndex:0];

    }

}
```

and changed "textViewDidChange" to this

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

float height = self.msg.contentSize.height;
    [UITextView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UITextView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    self.msgHeightConstraint.constant = height + 10.0; //Give it some padding

    [UITextView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: No need to grow the textview.

Comment: Only grow the textview till your view height. It is understandable that if you grow your textfield that much, then what is the need of scrolling, It will only work, when your texts are bigger then height of textview.

Comment: @ArpitParekh the innerScrollView has nothing to do with the growing text they are both in the outerScrollView .. the inner one has a fixed height(100) and has its own labels that I need some scrolling for them

Comment: Can you post a diagram. Pointing to which you are calling, inner scroll view and other stuffs.

Comment: TextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so the text view has an inbuilt facility to scroll, when the text is larger than the height of the text view.

Comment: @ArpitParekh please check my edit I've added an image

Comment: @ArpitParekh I tried changing height constraint based on content without using the class I mentioned above its still disables the scrolling in innerScrollView

Comment: Why you require the switch between two scroll view..?

Comment: @ArpitParekh because when scrolling in outer scrollview I cannot scroll in the inner scrollview so I have to switch

Comment: Enable both the scrollview, then try.

Comment: Have you wetted the contentSizes of the scroll view.

Comment: I can not understand your switching logic..

Comment: what is ScrollView 2

Comment: @ArpitParekh I tried enabling both still no luck also I set the content size based on the content in both scrollview each in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @ArpitParekh sorry my mistake scrollview 2 is the innerScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Please set the content size of the scroll view, Do not change anything in the code, and check,

```
  [self.scrollViewOuter setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 1000)];
    [self.scrollViewInner setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 1000)];
```

My both the scroll views are working if, I add content size in it.
[image]

Comment: Actually it is the main thing, you have to set for scrollview working.

Comment: Remove this method, scroll view did scroll, and run.

Comment: Where is your scroll view in view hierarchy ?

Comment: in my xib: View: --> outerScrollView --> View: --> innerScrollView and growing textviews

Comment: I set my contentsize like this  
  
    int outerContentHeight = self.outer_last_label.frame.size.height + self.outer_last_label.frame.origin.y;
    
    int innerContentHeight = self.inner_last_label.frame.size.height + self.inner_last_label.frame.origin.y;
    
    [self.outerSrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,outerContentHeight)];
    [self.innerScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollview2.frame.size.width, innerContentHeight)];

Comment: Till the time give the static content size's height and check .. like 3000, 4000

Comment: I put this in viewDidLoad and removed the old one but still the innerScrollView in not scrolling just the outer it like its being treated like any other labels :     [self.outerScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(3000,40000)];
    [self.innerScrollview.setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100,400000)];

Comment: self.outerScrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
        self.innerScrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: still same problem only outer is scrolling

Comment: do you use autolayout?

Comment: have you set the outlets properly.

Comment: I think it works for you because you are not using autolayout..this problem with autolayout and scroll view is a mess https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: although it is working the way I used to switch between them the problem is why is the growing text being affected by the scrollviews?

Comment: Do an edit of your question and make the above two comments in your question properly.

Comment: thanks but I managed to solve it not sure if what I'm doing is right but its working like I want it..check my edit and thank you anyways :)